# How to make input prompt not appear for condition

Tags: python

so i want this code to be like a 3 number calculator, but when the Y/N question is asked the question saying "Enter a third number still shows up, sorry if its a dumb question here is the code:

```
num1 = float(input("Enter a number: "))
num2 = float(input("Enter a second number: "))
question = input("Would you like to add another number? Y/N ")
num3 = float(input("Enter a third number: "))

if question =="Y":
    print(num1 + num2 + num3)
if question =="N": 
    print(num1 + num2 + num3
```

Comment: Have you considered moving the "input the third number" line to inside the `if` statement?

Comment: In other words, **if** you want code to happen under "some condition", then put that code _within that condition execution_

Comment: Also, note that when you move the third input, `num3` would be undefined when `question == "N"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to get `num3` if the value of `question` is `"Y"`.

```py
num1 = float(input("Enter a number: "))
num2 = float(input("Enter a second number: "))
question = input("Would you like to add another number? Y/N ")

if question == "Y":
    num3 = float(input("Enter a third number: "))
    print(num1 + num2 + num3)
else:
    print(num1 + num2)
```

Comment: If you know that `num3` won't be used, there's really no need for it in the "N" portion, right?

Comment: You're right, I updated the code. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could make the request for `num3` a condition from the answer of `question`. You can also set by default `num3` to 0 so that you don't need to have two separate cases for the addition.

```
num1 = float(input("Enter a number: "))
num2 = float(input("Enter a second number: "))
num3 = float(0)
question = input("Would you like to add another number? Y/N ")

if question =="Y":
    num3 = float(input("Enter a third number: "))
if question =="N": 
    // You could put some other stuff here

print(num1 + num2 + num3)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
num1 = float(input("Enter a number: "))
num2 = float(input("Enter a second number: "))
question = input("Would you like to add another number? Y/N ")
if question =="Y":
    num3 = float(input("Enter a third number: "))
    print(num1 + num2 + num3)
if question =="N":
    print(num1 + num2)
```